# How to implement scroll to a section/fragment on click in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to implement scrolling to a particular section on click in Liferay, but I have no idea how to add functionalities in Liferay.

I have created a page using multiple fragments and in the top of the page I have headers of the sections and on click of a header the page should be scrolled to that particular section.

[Attached page screenshot link below for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6wue.jpg)

Comment: According to your tags, you want to do this in Liferay 6 _and_ in Liferay 7, it _has to be_ in AUI and you're asking for how to do it using Eclipse. Correct? (otherwise, you might want to edit your tags)

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far and what worked? E.g. how do your current fragments look like? (see [ask])

Comment: @OlafKock I want to implement this in Liferay 7 and I am not aware of AUI but not in eclipse for sure and there are multiple fragments like About, Our History, Recent achievements added together to build a page.
And the headers which you see in the screenshot is also a separate fragment on click of a header it should scroll down to a fragment in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to scroll to some place on the page is to place an anchor there, e.g. with `<a name="scrollTarget"/>`. In your navigation, you'll just link to this by `<a href="#scrollTarget">Scroll to Target</a>` and you're set.

Of course, this can be done a lot fancier, with an animated scroll etc, but the basic start is this. There's nothing Liferay-specific hidden here - pick any of the more fancy methods, create fragments with the proper markup, and make sure they're used on your page.